# Are there any security concerns with running "bash -n FILE_OF_ARBITRARY_INPUT.txt"?

Tags: bash

If you were hypothetically writing a web service that checks the syntax of bash files, would there be any security concerns to running `bash -n` on any user input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As near as I can tell, `-n` should work as you expect, and yet I would still be cautious: I'm not aware of any serious examination of using `bash -n` for syntax-checking untrusted code, and  bugs in `bash` or in your C library, or really anywhere could have effects here that may be exploitable in ways that may be difficult to reason about.

It's always seemed prudent to *never* trust user input, and a big codebase like bash is a big place to hide bugs.

Here's what I would do:

- Prepare a chroot jail to run a statically-linked [restricted](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Optional-Features.html) bash
- Prepare a non-root user for purposes
- Write a script that constructs the jail from a template, chroots in with the source file, drops privileges, closes all fds except (1) and dups (2) to it, then finally runs `bash -n` with your program.